# Object reference error while retrieving gmail contact information

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

I am creating Google integrated asp.net Application. i want to retrieve all the information

of a friend of logged in user in gmail. I got the list of contacts in listbox. Now i want that

when i click on any of the contact in the list box it should display all the information

regarding that contact.

Here is the code:

```
List<ContactDetail> contactDetails = new List<ContactDetail>();
ContactsQuery query = new     
ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri(txtEmail.Text));

ContactsFeed feed = GContactService.Query(query);
foreach (ContactEntry entry in feed.Entries)
   {
       ContactDetail contact = new
       ContactDetail
       {
           Name = entry.Title.Text,
           EmailAddress1 = entry.Emails.Count >= 1 ? entry.Emails[0].Address : "",
           EmailAddress2 = entry.Emails.Count >= 2 ? entry.Emails[1].Address : "",
           Phone = entry.Phonenumbers.Count >= 1 ? entry.Phonenumbers[0].Value : "",
           Address = entry.PostalAddresses.Count >= 1 ? 
           entry.PostalAddresses[0].Value : "",
           Details = entry.Content.Content

       };

      contactDetails.Add(contact);
  }
```

But i got the following error on

```
ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri(txtEmail.Text));
```

error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace:

 [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
 Friends.GmailFriends.GetAllContact() in C:\Documents and Settings\Isha.Jain.QUAYMOHALI
 \Desktop\Friends\Friends\GmailFriends.aspx.cs:36
 Friends.GmailFriends.lstContacts_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
 C:\Documents and Settings\Isha.Jain.QUAYMOHALI\Desktop\Friends\Friends
 \GmailFriends.aspx.cs:95
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) +118
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +143
```

I am not able to understand why i am getting this error.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks.